# How to code the date calendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple form as you see, the DOB date of birth, field, I would like to have it 
with a date picker, how is the best way for this?

```
tr>
            <td>
                    <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel8" runat="server" Text="DOB:" Width="50px"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                </td>
            <td align="left">
                    &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbDOB" runat="server" Width="100px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
                </td>
            <td align="right">
                    <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel9" runat="server" Text="Weight:" Width="50px"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                </td>
            <td align="left">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbWeight" runat="server" Width="100px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
                </td>
            <td align="right">
                    <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel10" runat="server" Text="Height:" Width="50px"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                </td>
            <td align="left">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbHeight" runat="server" Width="100px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
                </td>
            <td align="right">
                    <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel11" runat="server" Text="BP:" Width="50px"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                </td>
            <td align="left">
                     <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbBP" runat="server" Width="100px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
                </td>
            <td align="right">
                    <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel12" runat="server" Text="Pulse:" Width="50px"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                </td>
            <td align="left">
                     <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbPulse" runat="server" Width="100px" ></dx:ASPxTextBox>
                </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: use Jquery Date Picker

Comment: Well you have a lot of options, there is an asp.net calendar control, there's client-side javascript (jQuery, a lot of other libraries,etc).

Comment: Try to use jquery date picker , http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: You can also use ajax calendar.  http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very simple way to do this would be to use **Jquery's built in datepicker** like this:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbDOB" runat="server" Width="100px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

and In the script tag:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tbDOB").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/WzLc3/3/

**ALSO:**

**If you cannot use Jquery** for your application, you can do this purely through asp.net but lightly more complicated by using the calander contorl.

here is a great tutorial for beginners to walk you through the steps,

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article746-how-to-create-a-date-picker-in-aspnet.aspx